# Installing ruboto

Tags: ruboto

I use this site
http://rubysource.com/ruboto-rubys-and-androids-first-born/#comment-41291
but while i create

```
ruboto gen app --package org.ruboto.example.quick_start --target android-7
```

It gives error

```
 /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find ruboto (>= 0) amongst [RedCloth-4.2.9, abstract-1.0.0, actionmailer-3.2.5, actionmailer-3.2.3, actionmailer-3.2.0, actionmailer-3.1.1, actionmailer-3.0.3, actionmailer-3.0.0.beta4, actionmailer-2.3.5, actionmailer-with-request-0.3.0, actionpack-3.2.5, actionpack-3.2.3, actionpack-3.2.0, actionpack-3.1.1, actionpack-3.0.3, actionpack-3.0.0.beta4, actionpack-3.0.0.beta3, actionpack-2.3.5, active_scaffold-3.2.12, active_scaffold_vho-3.1.4, active_utils-1.0.3, activemerchant-1.22.0, activemodel-3.2.5, activemodel-3.2.3, activemodel-3.2.0, activemodel-3.1.1, activemodel-3.0.3, activemodel-3.0.0.beta4, activemodel-3.0.0.beta3, activerecord-3.2.5, activerecord-3.2.3, activerecord-3.2.0, activerecord-3.1.1, activerecord-3.0.3, activerecord-3.0.0.beta4, activerecord-2.3.5, activeresource-3.2.5, activeresource-3.2.3, activeresource-3.2.0, activeresource-3.1.1, activeresource-3.0.3, activeresource-3.0.0.beta4, activeresource-2.3.5, activesupport-3.2.5, activesupport-3.2.3, activesupport-3.2.0, activesupport-3.1.1, activesupport-3.0.3, activesupport-3.0.0.beta4, activesupport-3.0.0.beta3, activesupport-2.3.5, acts_as_indexed-0.7.8, anjlab-bootstrap-rails-0.1.4, ansi-1.3.0, arel-3.0.2, arel-2.2.1, arel-2.0.10, arel-2.0.8, arel-2.0.7, arel-2.0.6, arel-0.4.0, authlogic-3.1.0, awesome_nested_set-2.1.3, awesome_print-0.4.0, aws-s3-0.6.2, babosa-0.3.7, bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1, bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4, blankslate-2.1.2.4, bson-1.6.4, bson-1.5.2, bson_ext-1.6.4, bson_ext-1.5.2, builder-3.0.0, builder-2.1.2, bundler-1.1.3, cancan-1.6.7, capistrano-2.12.0, carrierwave-0.6.2, carrierwave-0.6.1, carrierwave-0.5.1, carrierwave-mongoid-0.2.1, cells-3.8.5, chunky_png-1.2.5, ckeditor-3.7.1, clearance-0.16.3, cloudfactory-0.4.0, cocaine-0.2.1, codemirror-rails-2.24, coderay-1.0.6, coderay-0.9.8, coffee-rails-3.2.2, coffee-rails-3.1.1, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.3.3, coffee-script-source-1.3.2, coffee-script-source-1.3.1, coffee-script-source-1.1.2, columnize-0.3.2, commonjs-0.2.6, compass-0.12.2, compass-rails-1.0.3, configuration-1.2.0, countries-0.8.2, country_select-1.0.0, currencies-0.4.0, custom_fields-2.0.0.rc12, daemons-1.1.4, devise-2.1.2, devise-2.0.4, devise-1.1.9, devise-encryptable-0.1.1, diesel-0.1.5, dragonfly-0.9.12, ejs-1.0.0, erubis-2.7.0, erubis-2.6.6, eventmachine-0.12.10, excon-0.13.4, execjs-1.4.0, execjs-1.3.2, execjs-1.2.9, faraday-0.8.1, fastercsv-1.5.4, flash_cookie_session-1.1.3, fog-1.3.1, formatador-0.2.3, formatador-0.2.1, formtastic-2.0.2, friendly_id-4.0.7, fssm-0.2.9, galetahub-simple_captcha-0.1.3, globalize3-0.2.0, gmaps4rails-1.5.2, haml-3.1.6, haml_coffee_assets-0.9.4, hashie-1.1.0, heroku-1.17.10, highline-1.6.13, highline-1.6.12, highline-1.6.2, hike-1.2.1, httparty-0.8.3, httparty-0.8.1, i18n-0.6.0, i18n-0.5.0, i18n-0.4.2, i18n-0.3.7, i18n-js-2.1.2, jbuilder-0.4.0, jnunemaker-validatable-1.8.4, joosy-1.0.0.RC2, journey-1.0.4, journey-1.0.3, jquery-rails-2.0.2, jquery-rails-1.0.19, jquery-rails-1.0.14, jquery-rails-0.2.7, jquery-rails-0.2.6, jruby-pageant-1.0.2, json-1.7.3, json-1.7.1, json-1.6.6, json-1.6.1, json-1.4.6, kaminari-0.13.0, kaminari-0.10.1, kgio-2.7.4, launchy-0.3.7, less-2.2.1, less-rails-2.2.3, libv8-3.3.10.4-x86_64-linux, locomotive-aloha-rails-0.20.1.4, locomotive-mongoid-tree-0.6.2, locomotive-tinymce-rails-3.4.7.2, locomotive_cms-2.0.0.rc9, locomotive_liquid-2.2.2, mail-2.4.4, mail-2.3.0, mail-2.2.19, mail-2.2.15, mail-2.2.12, mail-2.2.7, memcache-client-1.8.5, metaclass-0.0.1, method_source-0.6.6, millisami-csv-hash-0.2.0, mime-types-1.19, mime-types-1.18, mime-types-1.16, mimetype-fu-0.1.2, mini_exiftool-1.4.2, mini_magick-3.4, mocha-0.11.4, mocha-0.9.10, money-5.0.0, mongo-1.6.4, mongo-1.5.2, mongo_mapper-0.11.1, mongo_mapper-0.8.6, mongoid-3.0.1, mongoid-2.4.11, moped-1.1.2, multi_json-1.3.6, multi_json-1.3.5, multi_json-1.3.4, multi_json-1.3.2, multi_json-1.0.3, multi_xml-0.5.1, multi_xml-0.4.1, multipart-post-1.1.5, mysql-2.8.1, mysql2-0.3.11, negative_captcha-0.3, negative_captcha-0.2.beta, net-ldap-0.3.1, net-scp-1.0.4, net-sftp-2.0.5, net-ssh-2.5.2, net-ssh-2.4.0, net-ssh-2.3.0, net-ssh-gateway-1.1.0, nifty-generators-0.4.6, nifty-generators-0.4.4, nifty-generators-0.4.2, nokogiri-1.5.5, nokogiri-1.5.2, oauth-0.4.6, oauth2-0.5.2, origin-1.0.4, orm_adapter-0.4.0, orm_adapter-0.3.0, orm_adapter-0.0.7, paper_trail-2.6.3, paperclip-3.1.2, paperclip-2.5.2, pg-0.14.0, pg-0.13.2, pg-0.11.0, pjax_rails-0.1.10, plucky-0.4.4, plucky-0.3.8, polyglot-0.3.3, polyglot-0.3.2, polyglot-0.3.1, prem-0.0.0, prototype-rails-3.2.1, pry-0.9.6.2, pry-doc-0.3.0, rack-1.4.1, rack-1.3.4, rack-1.2.5, rack-1.2.1, rack-1.1.3, rack-1.0.1, rack-cache-1.2, rack-cache-1.1, rack-mount-0.8.3, rack-mount-0.6.14, rack-mount-0.6.13, rack-openid-1.3.1, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rack-test-0.5.7, rack-test-0.5.6, rails-3.2.5, rails-3.2.3, rails-3.2.0, rails-3.1.1, rails-3.0.3, rails-3.0.0.beta4, rails-2.3.5, rails-backbone-0.6.1, rails3-generators-0.14.0, railties-3.2.5, railties-3.2.3, railties-3.2.0, railties-3.1.1, railties-3.0.3, railties-3.0.0.beta4, raindrops-0.10.0, rake-0.9.2.2, rake-0.9.2, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-3.12, rdoc-3.10, refinerycms-2.0.5, refinerycms-authentication-2.0.5, refinerycms-core-2.0.5, refinerycms-dashboard-2.0.5, refinerycms-i18n-2.0.0, refinerycms-images-2.0.5, refinerycms-pages-2.0.5, refinerycms-resources-2.0.5, render_component_vho-3.2.1, responders-0.6.5, responders-0.6.4, rest-client-1.6.7, rest-client-1.6.1, rmagick-2.13.1, rmagick-2.12.2, routing-filter-0.3.1, ruby-hmac-0.4.0, ruby-openid-2.1.8, ruby_parser-2.0.6, rubygems-bundler-0.9.2, rvm-1.11.3.3, sanitize-2.0.3, sass-3.1.20, sass-3.1.19, sass-3.1.18, sass-3.1.17, sass-3.1.10, sass-rails-3.2.5, sass-rails-3.1.4, seo_meta-1.3.0, sexp_processor-3.0.7, shoulda-2.11.3, slop-2.1.0, sorcery-0.7.12, sprockets-2.1.3, sprockets-2.1.2, sprockets-2.0.2, sqlite3-1.3.6, sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5, subexec-0.2.2, terminal-table-1.4.2, therubyracer-0.10.1, thin-1.2.11, thor-0.15.4, thor-0.15.3, thor-0.15.2, thor-0.14.6, thor-0.13.8, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.10, treetop-1.4.9, truncate_html-0.5.5, turn-0.8.3, twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.0.9, twitter_bootstrap_form_for-1.0.1, tzinfo-0.3.33, tzinfo-0.3.30, tzinfo-0.3.24, tzinfo-0.3.23, uglifier-1.2.6, uglifier-1.2.5, uglifier-1.2.4, uglifier-1.0.3, unicorn-4.3.1, unidecoder-1.1.1, warden-1.2.1, warden-1.1.1, warden-1.0.6, will_paginate-3.0.3, xml-simple-1.1.1, yard-0.7.2] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/ruboto:18:in `<main>'
```

someone please help me

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem using Ruby 1.9.x with Ruboto.  This is planned to be fixed in the next release of Ruboto, in august.  The issue is tracked here:  https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/pull/213

As a workaround, you can use Ruby 1.8.7 or JRuby 1.6.7.2 to run Ruboto.

Comment: do you have your own blog to install ruboto from begining? I read many blogs but all of them are messy. If u have perfect tuotorial then please recommend me.

Comment: Your best bet is the Getting Started tutorial:  https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto/wiki/Getting-started-with-Ruboto